# How to get the authid from OpenAM

Tags: session, gatling, openam, authid

I have a login web page.For example, `https://qa.xx/logon`. With a user id input box and a next button to go to the enter password page.

When users enter a user id and click next(POST request), it will send an auth request to OpenAM to get an authid for this request and then take the authid as form-data in the request body to make the POST request.

So my question is if I want to make the same POST request via Postman, how to get the authid? If I manually hit the openam auth page to get the authid and put it in the request body. When I make the POST request to enter user id, it is actual a new request and will get a new authid from openam.

Comment: If you only use username and password for authentication you can use zero page login feature of OpenAM. Authentication can be configure dynamically on AM side and your REST client must react on the Callbacks send by OpenAM REST authentication endpoint.

Comment: I think you are trying to Authenticate against a node, right ? Similar case what I have done is with this `https://URL/openam/json/realms/REALMNAME/authenticate?service=TreeName&authIndexType=service&authIndexValue=TreeName` I am retrieving authId and use that in subsequent call to OpenAM. The response from the above URL will be authID with CallBacks. Even this has worked from me on POSTMAN.